# Creating citation in ArcGIS Online map

Tags: arcgis-online

I would like to add a citation on the map (like for example the "powered from esri")  that would mention the researchers that created the displayed data, so if someone scrolls or zooms in out, it will be visible at all times.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000016132 Would this help?

Comment: @Carlos I think you should use that link as the basis to write an answer of a few paragraphs.

Comment: I am not quite sure @GeoF is referring to Web Maps or Web Map Apps, so I am hesitant to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is usually to add metadata (copyright/credits) for the citation, that then is displayed on the map using an Attribution widget or similar.

Depending on how the data is added to the map, and what sort of application you are using, the solution could vary.

For example, if you are using a hosted featurelayer on ArcGIS Online you can go the the item page and add/update the "Credits (Attribution)" for the item.  If you are using an application based on the 4x JSAPI, then it will be displayed by the Attribution widget at the bottom of the map.

- Example item: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8e937c9fc6484a8492981d5d05ecfe1f
- App: https://www.arcgis.com/apps/mapviewer/index.html?layers=8e937c9fc6484a8492981d5d05ecfe1f

And if you created the hosted featurelayer from ArcMap, see Carlos comment above about https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000016132